# Apache HttpClient зависает после 2 запросов

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

Вот такой код:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
String url = "https://www.yandex.ru/";
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

client.execute(request);
System.out.println(1);

client.execute(request);
System.out.println(1);

client.execute(request);
System.out.println(1);
```

После 2 запросов просто зависает и ничего не происходит. Раньше нормально было. Может быть, где-то ошибка, но найти не могу.

Comment: У меня бывают похожие ситуации, в которых истинный виновник еще не найден (через HttpClient запрашиваю свои же сервисы, висит на ожидании ответа из сокета, кажется), попробую над этим детальней посидеть, когда получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpClient` использует `connection pooling`. Изначально, размер пула равен двум. После выполнения 2 запросов, клиент зависает и ждет третьего.

Чтобы предотвратить такое поведение, необходимо "закрывать" полученный ответ перед тем, как отправлять следующий запрос.
Перепешите код таким образом:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);
httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().close();
System.out.println(1);
```

А вообще, для читабельности, было бы неплохо засунуть вышенаписанный код в цикл.